# Groovy String data to Date

Tags: groovy

How to convert String to Date ?

I tried this:

```
         @RequestMapping("/data/{data}")
     String buscar(@PathVariable String data, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute 'dataBuscar', data


    def newDate = data
    def df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy 00:00:00")
        data = df1.parse(newDate)


    model.addAttribute 'acessos', acessoService.buscar(data)


    'acesso/acesso.index'
}
```

but show me this message:
        Unparseable date: "12-01-2014"

Why? Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `SimpleDateFormat` pattern does not match the string you're trying to parse.

If you need to parse a string like "12-01-2014", you need:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Tested Groovy script:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
def date = format.parse("14-01-2014")
println date  // prints "Tue Jan 14 00:00:00 CST 2014"
```

As @tim_yates points out, Groovy provides the convenient method:

```
Date.parse('dd-MM-yyyy', "14-01-2014")
```

Comment: `Date.parse( 'dd-MM-yyyy', data )` is more idiomatic groovy

Comment: I did this, but continue show me the same message! 

Message: 

Unparseable date: "05-02-2014"

java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)java_text_DateFormat$parse.call(Unknown Source)org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108 ... 


Do you have another idea ?

Help me please!

Comment: Do not confuse `static Date parse(String format, String dateStr)` in Date with a deprecated method `long parse(String)` in `java.util.Date`

Comment: I tried to use Date.parse('dd-MM-yyy', data), but don't work, because the word parse appear like strikethrough word! Any idea ?

Comment: That's just a poor ide. Try running it

Comment: Show this : No signature of method: static java.util.Date.<$constructor$>() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [dd-MM-yyyy, 13-01-2014]

Comment: From 2.5.0, however, there has been a breaking change and those enhancements are not shipped anymore with groovy-all.

So, going forward, they need to be included as a separate module, named groovy-dateutil. [See here.](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-string-to-date)

Comment: how far back do I have to go for this to still be the deprecated `long parse()`?
`(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")).parse(foo.replace('Z',''))`