# String to date groovy

Tags: date, groovy

How to convert String to Date ?

I tried this:

```
@RequestMapping("/data/{data}")
    String buscar(@PathVariable String data, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute 'dataBuscar', data


    def newDate = data
    def df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy 00:00:00")
    data = df1.parse(newDate)

    model.addAttribute 'acessos', acessoService.buscar(data)

    'acesso/acesso.index'
}
```

but show me this message:

```
Unparseable date: "12-01-2014"

java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
java_text_DateFormat$parse.call(Unknown Source)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
br.com.owse.labs.owsetime.controllers.AcessoController.buscar(AcessoController.groovy:63)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:118)
com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:52)
br.com.owse.delorean.web.filters.SitemeshSpringFilter.super$2$doFilter(SitemeshSpringFilter.groovy)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
br.com.owse.delorean.web.filters.SitemeshSpringFilter.doFilter(SitemeshSpringFilter.groovy:37)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I need to parse this "12/01/2014 00:00:00"!

Why? Any idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Groovy String data to Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904526/groovy-string-data-to-date)

Comment: I know but I continue to have  problem!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The date you are trying to parse is `12-01-2014`, this can be done with:

```
String date = '12-01-2014'
Date d = Date.parse( 'dd-MM-yyyy', date )
println d
```

If your date was in the format `12/01/2014 00:00:00` (which it isn't), you could do:

```
String date = '12/01/2014 00:00:00'
Date d = Date.parse( 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', date )
println d
```

But that won't work in your code, as that doesn't seem to be the format for `data`

#### Update after comment below:

If you need the date back as a String in a different format, you can do:

```
String date = '12-01-2014'
String newDate = Date.parse( 'dd-MM-yyyy', date ).format( 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' )
assert newDate == '12/01/2014 00:00:00'
```

Comment: @NataliaRosa updated my answer (the assert is there just to prove it's in the required format for this example and isn't needed in your final solution)